# Python - How to speed us Nested for loop with function and multiple return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am writing a python code to compute if there is any fuzzy match between 2 strings. If there is a match, I have to store both the strings and the avg match value. The string to be compared are from a list that runs into thousands of entries
The issue is that the code is taking too long to execute. To speed up, I looked the other answers in here but none of them had multiple return values from the inner function in the loop. Looking for optimized code here...

```
tokens=['abc','bcd','abe','efg','opq']
valid_list=['acb','abc','abf','bcd','rts','xyz']
for i in tokens:
    for j in valid_list:
        token,valid_entry,avg_match=get_match(i,j)
        if(token!=0):
            potential_entry.append(valid_entry)
            match_tokens.append(token)
            ag_match.append(avg_match)

def get_match(i,j):

   avg_value=(fuzz.ratio(token,chk_str)+fuzz.partial_ratio(token,chk_str)+fuzz.token_sort_ratio(token,chk_str)+fuzz.token_set_ratio(token,chk_str))/4
    if(int(avg_value)>70):
        return token,chk_Str,int(avg_value)
    else:
        return 0,0,0
```

Comment: yes plz. I want to check the match of each token in input to each token in the valid_list.

Answer (score 1):

The main obvious thing I can see is that you could short circuit out of the fuzzy checks if any are clearly not going to be a valid match.

So instead of doing them all in one line, do them individually, and check if they are below a threshold before getting the other ratios, prioritise checking the ratio you'd expect to provide the clearest answer for this first.

Also, consider:

- using a single list of an object to avoid having to append to three lists
- using sets for your tokens and valid list to ensure there aren't any duplicate checks being done
- not casting the `avg_value` to an integer for the if statement, it doesn't really make a difference here.
- add in an explicit `i == j` check to return a 100% ratio before doing any other checks

Comment: Thanks @Sayse for the recommendations. I have removed the duplicates from both the lists. If I do not cast the value, I was getting float value error. I have also removed the tokens that are already matching exactly. The code I posted here is the example and so you see the exact match case. I will try to implement the list of object point.